# What are the errors in the output layer of back propagation algorithm for multi classification task?

Tags: python, machine-learning, backpropagation

I am using Python to implement a multi classification task. The output layer using softmax and The cost function is cross entropy function. I want to know the error in the output layer.

For the binary problem, the error of back propagation algorithm in output layer is y_pred - y.
What are the errors in the output layer of back propagation algorithm for multi classification task?

Comment: Not a single question mark is always a good sign, that you should overthink what exactly is your question ;)

Comment: I want to know the error of in the output layer of back propagation algorithm for multi classification task. so my question is "what is the error?"